# Is it safe to get address of shared_ptr<T> variable?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Is this code valid and safe? Will memory be leaked?

```
class Widget;
auto local_cache = LocalCache.GetInstance(); // init cache

{
   std::shared_ptr<Widget> tmp;
   local_cache.GetWidget(&tmp);
   // process with tmp
}
```

GetWidget() looks weird, it is actually a template like `GetWidget(T* value)` to pass in a value pointer for it to write to, and T is instantiated with `shared_ptr<Widget>`

```
void LocalCache::GetWidget(std::string k, std::shared_ptr<Widget>* w_ptr_ptr) {
    if (cache_map_ contains k) {
        *w_ptr_ptr = ... // copy-assigned 
     }
   
}

void LocalCache::PutWidget(std::string k, std::shared_ptr<Widget> v) {
     cache_map_.emplace(k, v);
     if (reach limit) {
          cache_map_.prune();
     }
}

void LocalCache::prune() {
     // prune the cache
}
```

Comment: This is fine, but why not pass by reference instead?

Comment: Could you describe, why you do not use `tmp = GetWidget()` and returning the `shared_ptr` by value?

Comment: @Sebastian I updated the background, because the api is like this, and if I want to store a pointer (for efficiency reason and  I choose shared_ptr)

Comment: Where do you suspect a memory leak? Which operation has you concerned? What do you suspect will happen?

Comment: Thank you. That helps to understand your requirements better. Is it okay/on purpose that with `prune()` there may still be active shared pointers to widgets around that you returned (copied into the passed ptr) by `GetWidget`? Is this covered? Or is the limit only for the cache/map itself?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, during pruning there might be active users using the returened shared_ptr<Widget>.  And this is why I use share_ptr<Widget>  instead of raw Widget* in the local_cache.  I just wonder is the weird get-addr-of-shared-ptr-then-copy-another-shared-ptr-to-it thing sound, will the resource be managed correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is sound, even if I would have returned by value (-> return-value-optimization)

Comment: Many styles guides require output parameters to be passed by pointer. You pass the address of an object that exists, so the function is sound. The design choice of using an output parameter is something the cache authors understand better than us.